# Concatenating the strings of selected rows for every column

Tags: r, string, concatenation

My data is as follows:

```
DF <- structure(list(toberevised = c("[Money amounts are in thousands of dollars]", 
NA, NA, NA, "Item", NA, NA, NA, NA, "Number of returns", "Number of joint returns", 
"Number with paid preparer's signature", "Number of exemptions", 
"Adjusted gross income (AGI) [3]", "Salaries and wages in AGI: [4] Number", 
"Salaries and wages in AGI: Amount", "Taxable interest:  Number", 
"Taxable interest: Amount", "Ordinary dividends:  Number", "Ordinary dividends: Amount"
), ...2 = c("UNITED STATES [2]", NA, NA, NA, "All returns", NA, 
NA, "1", NA, "135257620", "52607676", "80455243", "273738434", 
"7364640131", "114060887", "5161583318", "59553985", "161324824", 
"31158675", "164247298"), ...3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, "Under", "$50,000 [1]", 
NA, "2", NA, "92150166", "20743943", "53622647", "159649737", 
"1797097083", "75422766", "1541276272", "28527550", "39043002", 
"13174923", "23867893"), ...4 = c(NA, NA, "Size of adjusted gross income", 
NA, "50000", "under", "75000", "3", NA, "18221115", "11329459", 
"11025624", "44189517", "1119634632", "16299827", "896339313", 
"10891905", "16353293", "5255958", "12810282"), ...5 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, "75000", "under", "100000", "4", NA, "10499106", 
"8296546", "6260725", "28555195", "905336768", "9520214", "721137490", 
"7636612", "12852148", "4095938", "11524298"), ...6 = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, "100000", "under", "200000", "5", NA, "10797979", "9193700", 
"6678965", "30919226", "1429575727", "9782173", "1083175205", 
"9092673", "23160862", "5824522", "25842394"), ...7 = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, "200000", "or more", NA, "6", NA, "3589254", "3044028", 
"2867282", "10424759", "2112995921", "3035907", "919655038", 
"3405245", "69915518", "2807334", "90202431")), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

All I would like to do is concatenate for each column, rows 5, 6 and 7. I tried:

```
DF[,5:7] <-  lapply(DF[,5:7], paste(DF[,5:7],collapse=" "))
```

But I get the error:

```
Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : 
  variable names are limited to 10000 bytes
```

This happens even when I concatenate one row it with another empty row instead (which obviously should not be much more bytes)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lapply(DF[5:7, ], paste, collapse=" ")
```